# Store Current XML Element Name using MOXy or JAXB

Tags: xml, xpath, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I am using a combination of StAX and MOXy to parse XML files. When my parser detects that I am at a specified element, using XPaths, I unmarshal the element. Sometimes the XPath can represent multiple XML elements. Here is an example:

```
/a/b/*[self::c or self::d or self::e]
```

In this example these paths are all valid:

```
/a/b/c
/a/b/d
/a/b/e
```

In one of my POJOs I want to store the XML element name in a String variable, but I have not had any luck so far. The MOXy annotation @XmlVariableNode is very close to what I want, however I don't have a parent object and I don't want one. I have also tried using the MOXy annotation @XmlPath, but it seems that MOXy doesn't support the XPath functions name() or local-name(). Here is a simple example of my last attempt:

POJO

```
public class Data extends DataObject {

    private String source;

    public String getSource() {
        return source;
    }

    @XmlPath("./name()")
    public void setSource(String source) {
        this.source = source;
    }
}
```

unmarshaller:

```
protected DataObject unmarshallElement(Class<? extends DataObject> marshallingClass) throws JAXBException {
    DataObject retVal = null;

    if(marshallingClass != null) {
        Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbUnmarshallerMapping.get(marshallingClass);

        if(jaxbUnmarshaller != null) {
            JAXBElement<? extends DataObject> dataObject = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, marshallingClass);

            retVal = dataObject.getValue();
        }
        else 
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No unmarshaller could be found for " + marshallingClass.getName());
    }
    else 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No object class was provided");

    return retVal;
}
```

I am sure I could do something ugly in my unmarshaller like below, but I really don't want to.

```
JAXBElement<? extends DataObject> dataObject = jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, marshallingClass);

retVal = dataObject.getValue();

if(dataObject instanceof SomeClass)
    retVal.setSource(dataObject.getName().getLocalPart());
```

Is it possible to store the current elements name in a variable using MOXy or JAXB in general?

Comment: How about : `@XmlPath("name(.)")` or `@XmlPath("local-name(.)")`?

Comment: Moxy does not support name() or local-name, but only a small subset of XPath.

Comment: "I don't have a parent object and I don't want one"   - If I'm reading correctly you're saying you don't want to unmarshall a full document, but just a document subset?

Comment: Correct, I don't want the entire document just specific XPaths within the document.